# How to you make a JsonP request through a proxy?

Tags: qooxdoo

Hello I would like the `URL` argument to [qx.data.store.JsonP](http://demo.qooxdoo.org/current/apiviewer/#qx.data.store.Jsonp) to resolve through an HTTP proxy.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP proxies are handled at the browser level, JS code doesn't deal with that. You can use the URL to the JsonP server as if without a proxy. The proxy setup in the browser then handles the request routing. It should be transparent for your code.